# Computing a strange integral

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Prove that $(-1)^n \int_{-1}^1 (x^2 - 1)^ndx = \frac{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$

This one has me stumped. I've tried the obvious (using binomial theorem and then integrating termwise, or computing the upper sum for the partition with intervals of equal length and taking a limit [in fact, I still think this is the correct approach]) but can't get it to the right form.

This is an optional problem that appeared in an honours calculus course after the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: This formula is related to the legendre-polynomials.

Comment: Can you use the binomial theorem?

Comment: This is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 2):

Try integrating by part, you have:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)^ndx=\int_{-1}^{1}(x)'(x^2-1)^ndx=\left.x(x^{2}-1)^{n}\right|_{-1}^{1}-\int_{-1}^{1}x((x^2-1)^n)'dx=\\=0-n\int_{-1}^{1}x\cdot 2x \cdot (x^2-1)^{n-1}dx=\\=-2n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)^{n}dx+2n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)^{n-1}dx$$

Use this reccurence and induction.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that we don't have techniques of integration yet (parts, substitution, etc.)

Comment: But do we have integral $\int x^{m}dx$? I'll try write other prove.

Comment: Yes, we have that integral, and all the integrals gained for free by the FTC.